# Changing the size of a control dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms with Visual Studio 2010 and have 3 HTML server controls vertically placed one after another in the browser. I need to adjust the size of the third control based on how many items are there in the second control (the # of items is determined in the C# code-behind). How would I change the size of the second web server control dynamically based on a condition that is evaluated in the C# code behind? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of items is determined in the C# code-behind, you can set the size in code-behind as well. For example if your control with items is a DropDownList and control needs resizing is a TextBox, you can do something like this in C# code:

```
TextBox1.Style["Height"] = DropDownList1.Items.Count.ToString()  + "px";
```